# Amazon S3: "Business Personalized" Lifecycle Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would to build a lifecycle policy in Amazon S3 that if a certain business logic is triggered in the system, items that match that criteria would be removed from the bucket.

Essentially, once entries are deleted from the business database, they need to be removed 30 days *AFTER* the deletion prompt (in the business' tools). Is this something doable with Amazon S3,  and if yes, how?

Data is stored in an Amazon RDS instance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement I think you can trigger an event which marks an object for deletion in s3 via [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/).

From RDS Ther is not direct way to trigger a Lambda but what you can do is you can create an SNS Subscription and then trigger Lambda based on it , but problem is that there are limited event sources refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.html)

If it was using AWS Aurora there is way to this as you can refer from [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Lambda.html)

Comment: In our case, we are using Amazon RDS, not DynamoDB.